# Simple websockets chat client doesnt send messages

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to write a simple chat client using websockets, my code so far can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/purefan/dc5c1d161eae703b1b75bf2cf32874c0). If I programmatically send 2 or more messages it works, but as soon as I try to wait for user input no messages leave:

```
// This works
std::string message1 = "cpp1";
c->send(hdl, message1, websocketpp::frame::opcode::text);

std::string message2 = "cpp2";
c->send(hdl, message2, websocketpp::frame::opcode::text);
```

The program should take user input, so I tried:

```
do {
    std::cout << "What should I tell the ws?";
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    if (input == "exit") {
        keep_running = false;
    }
    else {
        c->send(hdl, input, websocketpp::frame::opcode::text);
        std::cout << "Told ws " << input;
    }

} while (keep_running);
```

This actually shows the "Told ws " message, but the ws server doesn't get the message. I confirmed the ws server works fine with a third party client (a google chrome extension). It looks as if the messages are being buffered but even when exiting the program they are not sent.

I am using the library [websocketpp](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp) and compiling under Visual Studio Community 2017

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A**SIO is **A**synchronous. This means you cannot block in callback which it invokes. If you block, no more callbacks will be fired because all the callbacks run on the same thread. This means your `while` loop in `on_open` prevents ASIO from processing any further messages or doing any further work towards sending your message.

You will need to find a way to read from `cin` asynchronously with respect to your socket. Probably the best way would be to not use `cin` and instead use the appropriate platform-specific [asynchronous stream](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/streams.html) provided by ASIO. For example, on Linux you might use a [posix::stream_descriptor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/posix__stream_descriptor.html) on file descriptor 0.

Another way would be to continue to use `cin` but from another thread. You could start a thread which reads from `cin` then posts the message to the main ASIO thread via `c.get_io_service().post(func)`.